# What language/instrument to use to test custom P2P communication protocol

Tags: testing, network-protocols

I have an embedded device performing some 20-25 commands of similar pattern received (via TIPC) from one controller(for example - PC).
I need to write tests for different sequences of commands to check the device functionality. Commands are initiating/stopping some processes in the Unit Under Test. The unit sends responses-statuses. I need to test that response is correct in each "scenario". For example:
Command: start operation A on channels 1 & 3.
Response: started A on 1 & 3.
Command: stop A on 3.
Response: stopped A on 3, A continues on 1.
There are some 10-12 operations on each channel, and some 5-7 channels (depends on configuration). Some operations are incorrect in some states, etc. So, I need to build "test scenarios" for each usage case.
In what language or/and in what environment (Linux preferable) is it better to do?
I looked at the TTCN3, but it seemed to me too heavy and complicated, although may be I am wrong... :-)

Comment: Why UDP instead of TCP though? Also, you didn't specify what should be tested, no? Are you testing the software, or are you testing the hardware responses?

Comment: Sorry for unclearness. Actually it is TIPC.. :-)   
Commands are initiating/stopping some processes in the Unit Under Test. The unit sends responses-statuses.   
I need to test that response is correct in each "scenario". For example:   
Command: start operation A on channels 1 & 3.   
Response: started A on 1 & 3.   
Command: stop A on 3   
Response: stopped A on 3, continue on 1.

Comment: In your Unit tests, specify Strings for each response and then just compare the received response with the expected String?

Comment: Mostly, yes. There are some 10-12 operations on each channel, and some 5-7 channels (depends on configuration). Some operations are in correct in some states, etc. SO, I need to build "test scenarios" for each usage case.
The questions is: in what language or/and in what environment?

Comment: Oh I see! I'd use whatever language you are fluent in. In my case I woulf just create some JUnit tests (java) in eclipse and run them from there.